# How to bind an array of objects and its properties to multiple html inputs with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using **AngularJS** for binding forms to a Java Script object, the way simple text inputs or checkboxes are associated on the go.

The problem is when I want to have in my *main object* an array of objects with multiple properties and these objects are dynamically added, or in other words, more objects can be added and so `html` elements to input their properties.

**I'm coding for [this site](http://registropsicologos.maricelaaguilarflores.com:2311/):**

These is where objects would be added to an array:

[image]

That whole row is equivalent to an object *`Posgrado`* and so *`Especialidad`*, *`Título`* and *`Cédula`* are its properties.

Clicking on *`Añadir`* button adds an input row (one more object). It can be seen here:

[image]

Each of these wil be at `professional.data.postgraduates`, an array of objects.

**How can I, using Angular:**

> - Manage the adding of more input *rows*.
> - Bind each input row to one single object and push it to an array.
> - Finally, bind the array to `professional.data.postgraduates`.

So far the only clue I have is using an extra **`Controller`** for such objects and maybe using some **`ng-init`** directives.

Here I got my whole **module** and markup:

```
(function() {


        var app = angular.module('PsicologosRegister', ['checklist-model'])

        app.controller('PsicologoController', function() {

            this.psycho = psicologo

            this.print = function() {

                console.log(this.psycho)
            }
        })

        app.controller('PersonalDataController', function() {

            this.data = datos_Personales

        })

        app.controller('ProfessionalDataController', function() {

            this.data = datos_Profesionales
        })

        app.controller('ProfessionalInterestsController', function() {

            this.data = intereses_Profesionales
        })              



        var datos_Personales = {}
        var datos_Profesionales = {}
        var intereses_Profesionales = {}

        var psicologo = {

                            datosPersonales:            datos_Personales,
                            datosProfesionales:         datos_Profesionales,
                            interesesProfesionales:     intereses_Profesionales
        }
})()

<div class="container" id="seccionRegistro1" ng-controller="PersonalDataController as personal">
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputNombre" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Nombre(s)</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputNombre" placeholder="Nombre(s)" ng-model="personal.data.name" >

    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputApellidos" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Apellidos</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputApellidos" placeholder="Apellidos" ng-model="personal.data.lastname">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEdad" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Edad</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEdad" placeholder="Edad" ng-model="personal.data.age">
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputTel" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Teléfono</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTel" placeholder="Teléfono" ng-model="personal.data.phone">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputCel" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Celular</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCel" placeholder="Celular" ng-model="personal.data.mobile">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputMail" class="col-xs-2 control-label">e-mail</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputMail" placeholder="e-mail" ng-model="personal.data.email">
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputFB" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Facebook</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFB" placeholder="Facebook" ng-model="personal.data.fb">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputDireccion" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Dirección</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDireccion" placeholder="Dirección" ng-model="personal.data.address">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Here is the markup refered in the questions above:**

```
<div class="container" id="seccionRegistro2" ng-controller="ProfessionalDataController as professional">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputAlmaMater" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Egresado de</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAlmaMater" placeholder="Egresado de" ng-model="professional.data.almaMater">
            </div>
        </div>              

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputAñoEgreso" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Año de egreso</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAñoEgreso" placeholder="Año de egreso" ng-model="professional.data.course">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputCedula" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Cédula Profesional</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCedula" placeholder="Cédula Profesional" ng-model="professional.data.cedula">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

            <label for="checkPosgrado" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Estudios de Posgrado</label>

            <div class="Posgrados" ng-init="numPosgrados = 1" ng-repeat="i in numPosgrados">

                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <select class="form-control inputPosgradoTipo">
                        <option>Especialidad</option>
                        <option>Maestría</option>
                        <option>Doctorado</option>
                    </select>               
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control inputPosgradoTitulo" placeholder="Título">                       
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control inputPosgradoCedula" placeholder="Cédula">
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-1">
                    <input type="button" class="form-control btnAñadirPosgrado" value="Añadir">
                </div>
                </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is much easier to accomplish in Angular than the way you are currently doing it.

Create a controller and define the options for the select list, and populate an array of postgraduates (I hardcoded a few, you would be pulling these from a database most likely).  Add a function to create a new postgraduate object and push it onto the array.

```
app.controller('ProfessionalDataController', function($scope) {

  $scope.tipos = [
    'Especialidad',
    'Maestría',
    'Doctorado'
    ];

  $scope.posgrados = [];   

 //If you wanted to assign records from a database, you could do it here.
 //$scope.posgrados = [
 // {tipo: 'Especialidad', titulo: 'titulo 1', cedula: 'cedula 1'},
 // {tipo: 'Maestría', titulo: 'titulo 2', cedula: 'cedula 2'},
 // {tipo: 'Doctorado', titulo: 'titulo 3', cedula: 'cedula 3'}
 //  ];

 $scope.addPosgrado = function(){
  var posgrado = {tipo: 'Especialidad', titulo: 'titulo', cedula: 'cedula'};
  $scope.posgrados.push(posgrado);
 }
```

In your view, you can create a table and iterate over the array of postgraduates, creating a row for each of them.  Wire up a button to call your addPosgrado function.

```
<body ng-controller="ProfessionalDataController">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Tipo</th>
        <th>Titulo</th>
        <th>Cedula</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="p in posgrados">
      <td><select ng-options="t for t in tipos" ng-model="p.tipo"></select></td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="p.titulo"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="p.cedula"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button ng-click="addPosgrado()">Añadir</button>    
</body>
```

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NTiKLmVwOc9HWHWJ1YCM?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, I think this might help to solve it. Just I'd like to make clear that I want this only for creating new, it's a register form. I won't have any initial `Posgrados`'s array at my controller and so I won't be pulling anything from database.

Comment: Ah, well that's even easier then.  Just set `$scope.posgrados = [];` in the controller.

Comment: Can you change a bit your answer in order to fit with my case? It will help me and other in future :)